# iOS UINavigationController barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer and UIButton interference

Tags: ios, iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uibutton, uinavigationbar

I have developed an app that makes use of the iOS8 feature to show or hide the navigation bar on a tap of the view.

However, the main view contains a UIButton which also act upon taps. The problem is that both 'objects' are receiving the tap and if I tap the button, the navigation bar toggles its visibility.

I can get to the *barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer* via the navigation controller but not really sure what can be done with it to stop it responding if a button is tapped.

Is there a way (apart from switching off or changing to 'Swipe to Hide') to subdue the navigation bar's appearance/disappearance when a button is pressed?

Comment: Did you try to solve with [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES]; ?

Comment: Well...thanks...that does actually help. It's just a bit tedious that I have to add it to every action handler in my view. I wonder if there's a 'global' way to tell it to not react to button taps.

Comment: Unfortunetelly there is not which i know. I always type that when i need but i will think about that if i figure it out i will write here. btw i added my answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
[self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES];
```

Comment: Thanks. It has helped

Answer (score 2):

Don't use the standard `barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer`. Fortunately, it's not hard to roll your own:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    let gestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: "toggleBarsOnTap:")
    self.view.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer)
}

func toggleBarsOnTap(sender: AnyObject?) {
    let hidden = !self.navigationBarHidden
    self.setNavigationBarHidden(hidden, animated: true)
    self.setToolbarHidden(hidden, animated: true)
}
```

Taps on the view will show/hide the bars, and taps on controls (subviews of the view) will not.